# MASM macro for separate lines output in MessageBox

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Now I just do an `offset` of one variable to output the data. Is there a way to do it as a repeatable macro, where I can use it 3 or more times, passing different strings of text as argument?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data   
wTitle db 'Result',0

person db "Line1",10
       db "Line2",10
       db "Line3",0

.code
start:
  invoke MessageBox,0,offset person,addr wTitle,MB_OK
  invoke ExitProcess,0
end start
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you wanted to create a convenience macro that accepts string literals, then you could do something like this:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\windows.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

Message MACRO title,msg
    LOCAL _szTitle
    LOCAL _szMsg
    .data
    _szTitle db &title&,0
    _szMsg db &msg&,0   
    .code
    invoke MessageBoxA, NULL, ADDR _szMsg ,ADDR _szTitle, MB_OK
ENDM

.code
start:

Message "Title","Hello world!"
invoke ExitProcess,0

end start
```

Comment: Thank you! The question is a little bit about different stuff, I want to call a macro for each line of text I want to output (in one MessageBox). Or, maybe this is easier to do in console. But it need to be called everytime I print a line. Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you just have one string with newlines in it? Why does it have to be multiple macro calls?

Comment: that is kinda what my first example does, there are 3 newlines made in advance. But I wanted to find a way to deconstruct a process of pushing lines a little and push it 1 by 1 from different variables.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you should build your complete message string first (using `StringCchCatA` or whatever), and then passing the address of that string to `MessageBox`.

Comment: if I try to do it in console, maybe there is the way to do it like that and pause the console so I can see the strings in console? For example `invoke StdOut` 3 times in a macro. How can I do that?

Comment: Like I said, first build the complete string, then pass it to `MessageBox`.